# How to make and save a video(avi) in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am learning matlab myself andI have made an animated plot using matlab;now i want to save it as an video file.can you tell me how to convert my animation into a video file in matlab.Below is my code

```
x=[1:2];
for i=1:25,
m=randi([3,5]);
n=randi([3,5]);
y=[m n];
bar(x,y)
axis equal                
A(i) = getframe;          
end
```

matlab version 7.8 R2009a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use avifile:

```
aviobj = avifile('example.avi','compression','None');
x=[1:2];
for i=1:25,
m=randi([3,5]);
n=randi([3,5]);
y=[m n];
bar(x,y)
axis equal        
aviobj = addframe(aviobj,gcf);       
drawnow 
end
viobj = close(aviobj)
```

Comment: hey tanks i tried this script bcoz its look easy..But the video which it made is not of good qualitiy..i cant see my results,its irregular..

Comment: From past experience some player has problem with no compression(VLC). try different player of change compression.Under win32  Cinepak works.

Comment: In my Matlab R2014b, `avifile` is not present anymore: "AVIFILE has been removed. Use VIDEOWRITER instead."

Answer (score 3):

If Matlab's avifile doesn't work (it might have problems with codecs of 64-bit OS), then use mmwrite.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15881-mmwrite

It's simple, and it works. I used it to create *.wmv files simply by: 
`mmwrite(filename, frames);`

Edit: code example

```
% set params
fps = 25;
n_samples = 5 * fps;
filename = 'd:/rand.wmv';
% allocate frames struct
fig = figure;
f = getframe(fig);
mov = struct('frames', repmat(f, n_samples, 1), ...
    'times', (1 : n_samples)' / fps, ...
    'width', size(f.cdata, 2), ...
    'height', size(f.cdata, 1));
% generate frames
for k = 1 : n_samples
    imagesc(rand(100), [0, 1]);
    drawnow;
    mov.frames(k) = getframe(fig);
end
% save (assuming mmwrite.m is in the path)
mmwrite(filename, mov);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to [print](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/print.html) the figure to an image, and then stitch the resulting image sequence into a video. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) are great tools for doing this. There are some great resources for describing this if you know the right search terms. I like this [one](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/)

In mencoder, you could stitch your images together with a command like:

```
mencoder "mf://*.jpg" -mf fps=10 -o test.avi -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=msmpeg4v2:vbitrate=800
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`VideoWriter`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) or see this [`forum discussion`](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/455886-how-to-save-animated-plots#answer_370280)