# Making A Movie In Matlab and Exporting It As Some Movie File

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, movie

Undoubtedly, this question has already been asked; however, after having searched for quite some time, I could not find anything relevant to my circumstances.

What I am trying to do is make a movie of plots that I generate through a for loop, and then export this movie file. How might I do this? Here is the chief part of my code:

```
 for j=1:N

        a=randi(L);
        b=randi(L);
        c=randi(L);
        d=randi(L);
        e=randi(L);
        f=randi(L);
        % Calculate energy at positions
        if lattice(a,b,c)==1 && lattice(d,e,f)==0

            %latticenew=lattice;
            %latticenew(d,e,f)=1;
            %latticenew(a,b,c)=0;
            E2=EnergyMC_1(lattice,mu,eps);

            dE = E2-E1; %Change in total energy of the system (gas) 
            %as the particle goes from its current positon to the randomly 
            %selected position.
%DeltaE = [DeltaE,dE];                            
                %Nsteps=Nsteps+1; %What does Nsteps do?
                if rand<exp(-dE*beta) %Factor of K is in there to reduce 
                    %the inverse temperature beta, so that the for loop can
                    %be longer than 15 iterations.

                    lattice(d,e,f)=1;
                    lattice(a,b,c)=0;
                    %lattice=latticenew;
                    E1=E2;
                    Accepted=Accepted+1;  
                    %drawnow 
                    [x,y,z] = ind2sub(size(lattice),find(lattice==1));
                     %position = [x,y,z];
                     %timelattice(:,:,j)=position;
                    plot3(x(:),y(:),z(:),'r.')
                    grid
                    %This is where the plotting occurs




                end

                HistoryE=[HistoryE, E1];

               end
     waitbar(j/N,H);



    end
```

EDIT:

Okay, I opened the link provided, and tried to follow the instructions given in the link. However, I can not get it to work. It makes a one movie plot, and then terminates, giving me the error

```
Error using avi
Unexpected Error. Reason: Failed to find the open file handle.

Error in avifile/addframe (line 188)
      avi('addframe',rot90(frame,-1), aviobj.Bitmapheader, ...

Error in Lattice_Project4 (line 104)
                    aviobj = addframe(aviobj,F);
```

I do not really understand what is being said. Here is my newly updated code:

```
    for j=1:N

        a=randi(L);
        b=randi(L);
        c=randi(L);
        d=randi(L);
        e=randi(L);
        f=randi(L);
        % Calculate energy at positions
        if lattice(a,b,c)==1 && lattice(d,e,f)==0

            %latticenew=lattice;
            %latticenew(d,e,f)=1;
            %latticenew(a,b,c)=0;
            E2=EnergyMC_1(lattice,mu,eps);

            dE = E2-E1; %Change in total energy of the system (gas) 
            %as the particle goes from its current positon to the randomly 
            %selected position.
%DeltaE = [DeltaE,dE];                            
                %Nsteps=Nsteps+1; %What does Nsteps do?
                if rand<exp(-dE*beta) %Factor of K is in there to reduce 
                    %the inverse temperature beta, so that the for loop can
                    %be longer than 15 iterations.
                    lattice(d,e,f)=1;
                    lattice(a,b,c)=0;
                    %lattice=latticenew;
                    E1=E2;
                    Accepted=Accepted+1;  

                    [x,y,z] = ind2sub(size(lattice),find(lattice==1));
                     %position = [x,y,z];
                     %timelattice(:,:,j)=position;
                    %drawnow 
                    plot3(x(:),y(:),z(:),'r.')
                     %camorbit(1+j/10000,0);
                    grid
                    F=getframe(fig);
                    aviobj = addframe(aviobj,F);   



                end

                HistoryE=[HistoryE, E1];
                close(fig);
                aviobj = close(aviobj);
               end
     %waitbar(j/N,H);


    end
```

Answer (score 1):

after "This is where the plotting occure", write:

```
Mymovie(j)=getframe;
```

Then after the code ends you can save the movie following these answers [How to make and save a video(avi) in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157558/how-to-make-and-save-a-videoavi-in-matlab)

Comment: I edited my post. Could you possible take a look?

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough. I was already aware of the post you linked; the reason why I asked this question, despite knowing, is because I did not understand the answers.